# How to know your recursive function has ended

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

I have a recursive function that travels all the directories and puts the bmp files in a JSON array, where keys or folders, and sub-arrays are the content of each folder (I don't know if I'm clear). For example, this file system :

`- data/
  |- hello/
    |- j.bmp
  |- t.bmp
 - ok/
  |- c.bmp`

would give something like this :

```
{"data":{
    "hello":{
      "j.bmp":"j.bmp"
    },
    "t.bmp":"t.bmp"
  },
  "ok":{
    "c.bmp":"c.bmp"
  }
}
```

So here is my code :

```
function preload(res_dir, nextfunc, errorfunc){
  let images = {}
  let c = document.createElement("CANVAS");

  function travelDir(directory){
    let dirReader = directory.createReader();
    dirReader.readEntries(function(subdirs){
      subdirs.forEach(function(entry){
        if (entry.isDirectory){
          let path = entry.toURL().replace(res_dir.toURL(),"").split("/");
          let a = images;
          for (var i = 0; i < path.length - 2; i++){
            a = a[path[i]];
          }
          a[entry.name] = {};
          travelDir(entry);
        } else if (entry.name.substr(entry.name.length - 4, 4) == ".bmp"){
          loadres(entry);
        }
      });
    }, errorfunc);
  }

  travelDir(res_dir);

  function loadres(file){
    let a = images;
    let path = file.toURL().replace(res_dir.toURL(),"").split("/");
    for (var i = 0; i < path.length - 1; i++){
      a = a[path[i]];
    }
    a[file.name] = file.name;
  }
}
```

The travelDir function travels through all the directories starting at res_dir, creates the key when it's a directory, else invokes loadres which adds the file name in the JSON array `images`

This works pretty well, but how do I know when these functions traveled through all the directories?
(If you want, I need to execute the function `nextfunc` at the end of the whole process, taking `images` as an argument, when it contains the entire file tree)

Comment: When the first call returns, I guess :-)

Comment: @leaf: nope, because `dirReader.readEntries` is async

Comment: Indeed, when the first call returns, I only have a list of the sub-directories of res_dir : the travelDir function only executed once, for res_dir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your code is async, recursion isn't simple to manage. You can't just call `travelDir` from within itself, because the parent function is only complete when the child is complete, and that is not the moment you're calling it.

If your toolchain is ES7-enabled, then simply use `async/await`, that is:

```
async function travelDir(directory) {
    .... await travelDir(subdir)
}

await travelDir(root)
nextfunc()
```

Otherwise, instead of spawning a child directly, place it in a queue and have a callback that processes the next item from the queue and invokes `nextfunc` once it's empty, along the lines of

```
let queue = [];

function step() {
    if (!queue.length)
        nextfunc(); // <-- ends here
    else
        travelDir(queue.shift())
}

function travelDir(directory) {
    ...
    dirReader.readEntries(parseEntries, errorfunc);
}

function parseEntries(subdirs) {
    subdirs.forEach(function (entry) {
        if (entry.isDirectory)
            queue.push(entry);
        else ...
            loadres(entry);
    });
    step() // <-- indirect recursion
}

queue.push(res_dir)
step()
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there was async in Javascript, but that makes sense. I will try these solutions !